# What's this unknown structure I found under an igloo?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was mining in a snow biome, and I suddenly fell into a small igloo, which was furnished with a bed, furnace, and crafting table. There was no door, and the floor was covered with carpet. There was no village nearby. Even stranger, when I went to mine the carpet, there was a trapdoor underneath, which led down a short shaft. At the bottom of the shaft was a larger room with a cauldron, brewing stand, and a chest containing a few items. There were two small indents in the back wall of the room, one of which held a villager trapped behind iron bars.

Does anyone know what that structure is called? The version of Minecraft I was playing was 1.20.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a different kind of igloo.

> In half of all igloos, an oak trapdoor can be found under the carpet (the third white carpet straight ahead from the doorway), leading down a long ladder shaft to a basement. This passageway and the basement are built from stone bricks, some of which are infested blocks with silverfish. In this basement there is a brewing stand, a cauldron and a loot chest. Beyond the far wall, behind iron bars in two different cages, are a villager and a plains zombie villager.

This is from [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Igloo).